# How can I change the server time within my node application's instance

Tags: node.js

I have an application that is heavily time dependent. To make testing easier I would like to be able to start my node application at specific points in time.

```
NODE_FAKE_TIME=true node app.js
```

I am using something like this inside of my app.js

```
if(process.env.NODE_FAKE_TIME) { 
  var time = parseInt(moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 04:00:00')).format('XSSS'));
  var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(time, "Date");    
}
```

However is there a better way to do this other than using sinon's useFakeTimers? Because by doing this yes it does change the clock time.... however it affects other things like setIntervals and setTimeOuts.

I just want a clean way of specifying the time in the application's eyes so everywhere I am using Date.now it will go off the time I specify at runtime.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I've done this in unit tests by directly replacing methods on Date:

```
    var oldNow = Date.now;
    var oldGetTime = Date.prototype.getTime;

    Date.now = function() { return 0; }
    Date.prototype.getTime = Date.now;
```

The above sets time since 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 to zero - just replace the returned value with the time you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do this is to use var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(date, "Date"); and then use clock.tick(1000).

Allows you to specify what the date should be at run time by providing the date in a timestamp and then specifying how many MS between ticks.

Example:

```
  var time = some_timestamp_here;
  var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(time, "Date");

  // Every second tick the clock ahead one hour
  setInterval(function(){
    clock.tick(3600000);
  }, 1000);
```